# Mongo get limited and sorted latest documents in reverse order

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, limit, reverse

Given a collection with a field called timestamp (int), I want to get the n latest records, in Ascending order.

for example, given:

```
collection: [
    {_id: 1, timestamp: 1}
    ...
    {_id: 100, timestamp: 100}
]
```

If I query it like this, I will get:

```
# The combination of sort by DESCENDING with limit gives me the latest part of the collection, which is what I want.
collection.find({}).sort({"timestamp": DESCENDING}).limit(3)
# I will get:
[{_id: 100, timestamp: 100}, {_id: 99, timestamp: 99}, {_id: 98, timestamp: 98}]

# though I wanted to get the result in ASCENDING order:
[{_id: 98, timestamp: 98}, {_id: 99, timestamp: 99}, {_id: 100, timestamp: 100}]
```

The problem is that the "sort()" function I'm using to filter with the limit reverses my cursor.

I will paste my pythonic "workaround" in the answers, but I will be happy to find some pure mongo operation.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the `skip` function on the _cursor_? `skip` along with `limit` and `sort` has possibilities.

Comment: I think skip could have worked if skip could have gotten negative values, but it cant. Otherwise, you need to know how many docs are in the collection and subtruct from that the number of docs you want, that you don't know...

Comment: Maybe you can add another sort with ascending at the end.

Comment: You can't sort then limit then sort again in mongo. "sort and limit commands are actually modifications to the query that gets sent to the mongodb server" as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328335/8808983

Comment: Then, you can use an aggregation query with, `$sort`, `$limit` and `$sort` stages. Each aggregation stage returns transformed data, which is input to the next stage. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm doing it in python, Is there any better way which is pure mongo?

```
MAX_DOCS_TO_PROCESS = 3
filter = {}  # can be anything
result_cursor = collection_name.find(filter).sort("timestamp", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(MAX_DOCS_TO_PROCESS)

# Here the cursor will give:
# [{_id: 100, timestamp: 100}, {_id: 99, timestamp: 99}, {_id: 98, timestamp: 98}]

result_list = sorted(result_cursor, key=lambda doc: doc.get("timestamp", 0))

# Here the list will be:
# [{_id: 98, timestamp: 98}, {_id: 99, timestamp: 99}, {_id: 100, timestamp: 100}]
```